# Count columns according to dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, count

I need help with a SQL statement. The goal is to count the amount of alarms of each date. My table looks something like this:

```
|----DATE----|---COUNTER---|---ALARM_ID---|
|2012-01-01  |     30      |      1       |
|2012-01-01  |     20      |      2       |
|2012-01-01  |     10      |      3       |
|2012-01-02  |     5       |      1       |
|2012-01-02  |     25      |      2       |
|2012-01-02  |     12      |      3       |
|2012-01-03  |     33      |      1       |
|2012-01-03  |     43      |      2       |
|2012-01-03  |     11      |      3       |
```

And I'm looking for a SQL statement that gives this result:

```
|----DATE----|---COUNTER---|
|2012-01-01  |     60      |
|2012-01-02  |     42      |
|2012-01-03  |     87      |
```

I've been working on this **SELECT date, SUM(counter) FROM all_stats** but all I get is:

```
|----DATE----|---COUNTER---|
|2012-01-01  |     60      |
```

Do I have to create a loop to go through all dates and count?

Thanks in advance, Steve-O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date, SUM(counter)
FROM all_stats
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
SELECT date, SUM(counter) FROM all_stats GROUP BY date;
```

"GROUP BY date" puts all the individual dates on a separate line and does the sum separately per date.

Answer (score 1):

```
select date, sum(counter)
from all_stats
group by date
```